# List.js Not Sorting

Tags: javascript, list.js

I have a simple list at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/ExYEoLj) that I am trying to sort by number but it is not seem to work. I am following the documentation shown for basic list shown [here](https://listjs.com/). What am I missing? Thank you.

js for list

```
var options = { 
  valueNames = ['date', 'number'] 
};
var ResultDiv = new List('ResultDiv', options);
```

Comment: Typo: `valueNames : ['date', 'number']` use this instead of   `valueNames = ['date', 'number'] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with:

```
var options = { 
  valueNames : ['date', 'number'] 
};
var ResultDiv = new List('ResultDiv', options);
```